# MUI datagrid custom pagination not working with server side pagination

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination, datagrid

Mui datagrid custom pagination is not working when it set to server side pagination and passed mui Pagination component. You can find the codesanbox link below and try enabling/disabling the slots props. You will find the without slot there are many pages but after adding slot it always 1 page. did lots of search but couldn't find any thing.

Please help!

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/purple-grass-3m7kxm)